# Import CSV from URL and store into SQL Server table without downloading the file

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv, httpresponse

I've implemented a web and Windows application which hit an URL containing path to the csv file. I'm using `WebClient` to download the file and then read data from `.csv` and write into a SQL Server table.

Is there a way to do this without downloading/saving the `.csv` and writing the response `.csv` of the URL into the SQL Server table using a stored procedure?

Below is snippet of my working C# code.

```
URL_VALUE = "http://test.url.com/table.csv?test.csv";
string csvPath = "~C:\\SaveFile\\test.csv";

WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(@URL_VALUE, csvPath);

writeToSQL(csvPath, Symbol);

// Code snippet for SQL Write operation
public void writeToSQL(string url, string filepath)
{
    using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
    {
        // Set the database table name
        sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.csv_PopulateData";

        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Col1", "Val1");
        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Col2", "Val2");
        sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Col3", "Val3");

        sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whether this is possible or not, from a security point of view I would always avoid having database communicating directly to the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'll try writing a RESTFull API which will get the httpResponse in JSON/XML format and then write into SQL Server Table.

Comment: Using `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` methods I was able to pull data from a `.csv` file present on URL and write into a SQL Server table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` methods I was able to pull data from a `.csv` file present on URL and write into a SQL Server table.

```
public void getFileData()
    {
        try
        {

            Uri CSVUri = new Uri("URL");
            WebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(CSVUri);
            webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.GetResponse();
            if (webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader strReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(WebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
                //create datatable with column names (Headers)
                Createtable(strReader.ReadLine());
                String SingleLine;
                while ((SingleLine = strReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    AddRowtable(SingleLine); //Add data into dataset
                }

                GridView1.DataSource = datatable1;

                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
                {
                    foreach (DataColumn c in datatable1.Columns)
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName);

                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.tableName";
                    try
                    {
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(datatable1);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string display = "Exception Occured";
                        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
                    }
                }

                if (strReader != null) strReader.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException ex)
        {
            string display = "Exception Occured";
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('" + display + "');", true);
        }
    }
```